# What do you call a person who is getting their turn on a board game?

Tags: vocabulary

For example, I'm playing a snake and ladder board game, and now it's my turn. What am I called? Is there a term or a phrase in English that basically means "the person who is getting their turn in a board game" (or any kind of turn based activity really)

Comment: Could you write the sentence that you want to say? There's a very useful word "it" for this, but you use this only in specific situations. For example, if we're playing a game, and it's your turn, I'd say "you're *it*." However, if I'm writing an instruction manual or explaining a rule of a game abstractly, and refer to the person who's turn it is, perhaps the current answer is best, "the current player" for example. Certain two-player games have specific traditional names for each of the two players, e.g. in chess, the players are referred to as White and Black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In writing, for example in instructions for a game, the terms "the active player" and "the current player" are both used. As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20active%20player%2C%20the%20current%20player&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20active%20player%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20current%20player%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20active%20player%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20current%20player%3B%2Cc0) shows, the two terms vary in popularity over time, and usages of both terms is increasing.

When speaking about yourself, you would simply say "It's my turn". To speak to somebody, you would say "It's your turn" and to speak about somebody else, you would say "It's Ahmed's turn."

Comment: Maybe you'd write these phrases in an instruction manual. But when speaking in (American) English, we would usually say *it* for this, e.g. "you're it". Try expanding your NGram analysis to include phrases like "you're it", "who's it" and so on.

Comment: @Brandin, I had a quick look, but most of the references to "you're it" are either to do with the game of tag, or not related to games at all. I couldn't find any references to its usage in relation to board games.